# Lyx template for scientific paper

Tags: pdftex, templates, lyx

Anyone know of any simple Template for scientific paper which is easy to modify and looks great? So that i don't have to use several hour to find out the syntax.

Comment: If you do it once, you can keep using it again, and again, and again... In any case, "looks great" is really a subjective thing. Can you be more clear on what you actually want?

Comment: One option, of course, is to just go to http://arxiv.org/, find a paper whose formatting you like, and download the source (on the RHS, under Downloads, click "Other formats" which will allow you to download source when available). And then you can just strip the body and be left with a skeleton file you can just fill out.

Comment: RHS? where can i find that?

Comment: I'd look on the Right Hand Side.

Comment: Oops! I forgot I am not at MathOverflow where RHS is standard abbreviation. Right Hand Side is indeed what was meant. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single format for a "scientific paper." It really depends what you're writing. Journal and Conference papers typically have a style mandated by the publisher/organizer.

Comment: They might not even accept TeX: without at least some context how can we tell!

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand what you're saying there. What did you test?

Answer (score 1):

The very elegant [classicthesis template](http://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) by André Miede has been ported to LyX by Nick Mariette. It's available here:

- http://www.soundsorange.net/resources/classic-thesis-for-lyx/

For further templates like this, have a look at

- the [Example/Thesis](http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Thesis) category in the LyX wiki,
- [www.thesis-template.com](http://www.thesis-template.com/) collecting such LyX and LaTeX templates

and the links on those pages. You would find nice and customizable scientific LyX templates there.

LaTeXtemplates.com contains a section

- [Theses templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses)

The latter is LaTeX, not LyX, but a template can be a great start to change to LaTeX.

Comment: The Example/Thesis page is useful, but the soundsorange link is now broken. The LyX wiki seems to give a more direct link to the classicthesis downloads at https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads/